# renaming files in SFTP session

Tags: rename, sftp

This is part of a **SFTP** file transfer.

Here are the steps:

1. Check files with `.csv` extension and get them to the local directory.
2. After that, move them to the another folder in the remote connection.

Tried using the `rename` command but it throws an error **"Failure"**

Tried using `-b` batch-file option with sftp but looks like `rename` command needs a specific file-name instead of a set of files.

So how do I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you have permissions to remove the file? Do you have permissions to put the file in the remote new folder?

Comment: yes I do. I was not giving the destination filename and thats the reason it was failing

Answer (score 9):

Works for me, so you will need to provide more information about the problem:

```
chris@localhost$ finger 2> file.txt
chris@localhost$ sftp remotehost
Connected to remotehost.
sftp> ls -l file.txt
Can't ls: "/home/chris/file.txt" not found
sftp> ls -l file.tmp
Can't ls: "/home/chris/file.tmp" not found

# So the file doesn't exist on the remote in either form

sftp> put file.txt file.tmp
Uploading file.txt to /home/chris/file.tmp
file.txt                                                      100%  501     0.5KB/s   00:01
sftp> ls -l file.txt
Can't ls: "/home/chris/file.txt" not found
sftp> ls -l file.tmp
-rw-r-xr--    0 1001     1001          501 Aug 12 16:35 file.tmp

# It has arrived as file.tmp

sftp> rename file.tmp file.txt
sftp> ls -l file.txt
-rw-r-xr--    0 1001     1001          501 Aug 12 16:35 file.txt
sftp> ls -l file.tmp
Can't ls: "/home/chris/file.tmp" not found

# And been successfully renamed
```

Comment: Thanks , But when i try to pass as arguments, it doesnt read the filename from a while loop.

Comment: When i use this rename "$Remote_server_source_path/$filename" "$Dest_path/$filename"

Comment: Sorry, i posted the comment before it was complete. Here is the code i wrote

Comment: cat tempfilelist | while read line
do

#echo $line
echo "Filename to be moved : "
filename= echo $line | awk '{print $9}'
echo $filename

sftp $LOGIN  << EOF
cd $Remote_server_source_path
pwd
rename "$Remote_server_source_path/$filename" "$Dest_path/$filename"
bye
EOF
done

Comment: @shravani please [update your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/222803/edit) to include this new information. Otherwise it can get too spread out and lost in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Roaima,. The issue is solved now. I was able to rename the file .

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the `rename` command in sftp does *NOT* work when the source and target are on different file systems.

I see this behaviour in RedHat6, SLES9, and more.

Answer (score 0):

This might not exactly be what the OP wanted however,
I found sftp `!command` to be helpful for "renaming files in SFTP session".

- From sftp help: "!command  - Execute 'command' in local shell"

Here's my usage from SFTP session - (Local: macOS Catalina, Remote: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

```
sftp> lls
blankFileForVSCODEbrowser.txt   counties
sftp> !command mv  blankFileForVSCODEbrowser.txt blankFileForVSCODEbrowserRenameTest.txt
sftp> lls
blankFileForVSCODEbrowserRenameTest.txt counties
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash shell you can try doing following (can also shrink it to oneliner):

Renaming all csv files to txt on remote sftp $server/$dir (assuming passwordless access):

```
for f in `echo 'ls *.csv' | sftp -qp $user@$server:$dir | grep -v ^sftp`; do
    echo "rename '$f' '${f%.csv}.txt'" | sftp -qp $user@$server:$dir ;
done
```

or

```
# to move to $newpath folder:
for f in `echo 'ls *.csv' | sftp -qp $user@$server:$dir | grep -v ^sftp`; do
    echo "rename $f $newpath/${f##*/}" | sftp -qp $user@$server:$dir ;
done
```

where

- `echo 'ls *.csv' | sftp $server:$dir` - runs ls on remote sftp in dir $dir
- `${f%.csv}.txt` - replaces csv with txt in variable $f
- `${f##*/}` - remove path from filepath $f (just in case)

P.S. if you need to enable interactive entering of password - try adding `-o "BatchMode=no"` argument to `sftp`